# Auth0 + Asp.Net Core 2.1 + Error 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, auth0, asp.net-core-2.1

it's my first experience with Auth0 , I create My Asp.net Core Web API 2.1  , when I finished implementing my Controllers , I would secure them with Auth0 .
I follow the docs of Auth0 to configue it in Startup.cs Like That in ConfigureServices method :

```
    // 1. Add Authentication Services
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://studentdz.eu.auth0.com/";
        options.Audience = "https://api.studentdz.com";
    });

    services.AddMvc()
         .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

and in Configure method :

```
        // 2. Enable authentication middleware
        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

After That I create User in my Dashboard in Auth0 and I assing it a role that I create It like that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XwuA.png)

if i just use in  my controller the Attribut `[Authorize]` it's normal .  
but if I Add role to yhis Attribut like that : `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` 
the result will be **Error 403 forbidden**

Please Help to Find A solution

Comment: I would suggest to go for asp.net core 3.1. You would find more samples/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Please review all this tutorial
[ASP.NET Core v2.1: Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/aspnet-core/03-authorization#restrict-access-based-on-user-roles)

This tutorial explain all that you need for Role base authentication

Comment: The Controller example that they gave is very simple code as mine , but still not work in my Project.

Comment: Ok, Recap:
1 - From Auth0 you need create a new rule, this rule allow you verify the role, in the example they verify the domain for identify what is the role, then inside same rule they add the role to the token with the namespace `https://schemas.quickstarts.com/roles`
2- From your project in the Startup class add the `TokenValidationParameters` and inside add the claims for role
Not all responsability is from the controller

Comment: I resolve it , The probleme was in Postman when I asked for the access token using wrong grant-type , so when I convert the token in jwt.io , I didn't  found the role.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Witch grant_type did you use/need?

Comment: I guess we'll never know...